# Series Solution To Differential Equations - Need help with one step

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Would someone kindly explain to me what the logic is behind one of the steps here:

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SeriesSolutions.aspx

In Example 1 -

Following on from this sentence on the page

**"Now, at this point we just need to start plugging in some value of $n$ and see what happens"**

I get the plugging in $n's$ part, I just don't understand the steps behind writing all of the even $a's$ in terms of $a_0$ and all of the odd $a's$ in terms of $a_1$

For example  they have $a_4$ = $-\dfrac{a_2}{(4)(3)}$ which they then re-write as

$a_4$ = $\dfrac{a_0}{(4)(3)(2)(1)}$

Can anyone explain how this step works?

Let me know if you need clarification, thanks.

Comment: By a simple substitution. $\displaystyle a_2 = \frac{-a_0}{(2)(1)}$, so $\displaystyle a_4 = \frac{-a_2}{(4)(3)} = \frac{-\frac{a_0}{(2)(1)}}{(4)(3)} = \frac{a_0}{(4)(3)(2)(1)}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n=0$, we discover $a_2 = \frac{-a_0}{(2)(1)}$.  We expect this from the recurence $a_{n+2} = \frac{-a_n}{(n+2)(n+1)}$.  Setting $n=2$, we get $a_{2+2} = \frac{-a_2}{(2+2)(2+1)}$.  But we already know $a_2$ and plugging this in for $a_2$ we get 
$$a_{4} = \frac{-\frac{-a_0}{(2)(1)}}{(4)(3)} = \frac{a_0}{(4)(3)(2)(1)}$$

Comment: Never looked at it that way, thanks!